# Umbraco uSync folder isn't on webserver after web publish

Tags: umbraco, web-publishing

I have my website running local with the database on my server. On that i have Umbraco and some datatypes. I store all of that with uSync in a folder and then publish my site with Web Publish to my server. On the server I have then my site with Umbraco running. But i can't see the pacage uSync and can't install it. 
 
How can i get my elements on my server running?

Comment: Are you pointing at the same dB from both local website and sever website?

Comment: Also which versions and how was umbraco and usync installed. Is usync actually enabled?